# How to generate pdf from docx - NodeJS + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, pdf-generation, nestjs

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a previously generated DOCX file in NodeJS. I'm using NestJS and TypeScript.
I have tried many ways, but everything fails:

- **@nativedocuments/docx-wasm**: NativeDocuments isn't working anymore.
- **word2pdf**: Is archived at github, and unavailable at npm.
- **docx-pdf**: Generates an unstyled pdf. It removes my tables, indentation,
  justified text, etc.
- **libreoffice-convert**: Throws a window error: The
  application cannot be started. The configuration file "C:/Program
  Files/LibreOffice/program/bootstrap.ini" is corrupt (But LibreOffice software is working with no problem).

Do you know some workaround to the problems I got with any of the previously mentioned docx to pdf alternatives? Or maybe some other alternative that I can use (For free, please)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I know about is using Libreoffice. You don't really need a wrapper library for that.

You can just execute libreoffice directly using `exec`:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("libreoffice --headless file.xyz", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

You'll need to first write your DOCX to a file somewhere on the disk where Libreoffice would be able to open it, and the resulting PDF would be written on the disk as well - then you can load it into Node with fs.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/) to render PDFs from HTML documents. If you could manage to transform your DOCX file into HTML, this might be a viable option. It looks like there are [options](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js/) available to do so, but I can't vouch for them.